# Implement search in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I got the question to implement search in my Swagger UI which uses localhost.

I have been searching online and I didn't find an answer for this.

My question is: "Is it possible to implement search in the Swagger UI, so people can search for a path of the API?"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by implement search? Like a search box at the top? is the browser's search not enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have received an answer on the official Swagger community page on Google groups.

They suggested the following page on github and this was just what I was looking for. It is a very nice looking search implementation in the Swagger UI.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/2116

Anyway thanks for answering to my question!

Answer (score 0):

This [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) don't have a ui-search option so far. But as a solution you have 2 options.

1. By default swagger-ui list down the set of apis based on the paths (annotated by @Api() on api code). In the below example it has listed down apis based on 2 paths (price-checks and pdp-details).
   [image]

2.You can explicitly tell swagger-ui to only show apis listed under specific path. In below example, it shows apis listed under price-checks only.

[image]
To do that, you have to configure that path-doc with swagger.

Refer [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X) for more info about swagger-annotations.

UPDATE:

In- built swagger-ui [search](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/2116) is now available.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Not realy what I was looking for. Thanks anyway!

Comment: NP. I found a new thing from your answer too.

Answer (score -3):

There is a repository in github[swagger search](https://github.com/llz383455526/swagger-search) that can search API's across projects and search API in swagger document by command(ctrl)+F.